# Chemical bonding

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

How do we compare the strength of permanent dipole permanent dipole (PDPD) interaction? Is it by bond polarity? 
Since H-X (where X is halogen) is polar, and for bond polarity (PDPD bond strength): HCl > HBr > HI, why is it that for boiling point: HCl < HBr < HI which is inversely proportional to bond strength?

Comment: You can easily Google the answer.